# How to efficiently retrieve an Appoinment Ocurrence's index in EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

`Appointment.BindToOcurrence` takes the following arguments:

`service`, `ItemId`, and `Index`.

However, there doesn't seem to be an efficient way to get said index, given an occurrence, without looping over every single item in the series.

If I want to store some information that will allow me to retrieve a specific event in the series, regardless of what account is viewing the appointment, I can store `CleanGlobalObjectId` and ideally part of the recurring data, however, all you get is the ItemID (which is not global to all users), the Start, End.

How do I retrieve the index of a recurring item without doing a loop?